# Assign method to UISlider programmatically using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uislider

I add `UISlider` to view programmatically like this:

```
UISlider * sideslider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(canvasWidth +((canvasWidth) - (recwidth) / 4) /b2, recheight - 70, (recwidth) / 4, 20)];
[sideslider setMaximumValue:solution0->Plan->HDivisions.count];
// sideslider 
int slidervalue = sideslider.value;
[self addSubview:sideslider];
```

I need to add this event handler

```
-(IBAction)updateside:(UISlider *)sender;
```

to this slider after creating it ?

Comment: Apparently, yes, you do need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign:

```
[sideslider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

To figure out the value of the sender (`sideslider`):

```
-(IBAction)updateside:(id)sender
{
    UISlider * slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    NSLog(@"Slider Value: %.1f", [slider value]);
}
```